# Simply Queries in Premium Azure SQL DB Elastic Pool hogs DTU's

Tags: azure-sql-database

Here is the situation I am in:

In Azure, we have an elastic database pool that is a Premium 1000 eDTU pool.  We have 6 databases.  One of the databases runs merges and aggregations on reporting data at regular intervals and has been chugging along for several weeks with the MAX eDTU's at around 60% and average around 40%.

Monday this week, everything started going to crap.  We rolled NO CHANGES to ANYTHING.  Looking that the DB metrics in the azure portal, as well as the sys.dm_db_resource_stats view, our CPU% is getting hammered at 99-100% for blocks of up to an hour while the memory in that view is consistently around 10%.  We have reports that run off of this database, and some of the queries (when run in management studio) will bring the server to its knees.  These are not poorly-written or gigantic queries either.  For example, we have one query that runs two CTE's and joins the results together for final output.  The first returns 30 records and the second returns 20 (each returning 4-5 columns).  When I parameterize the query and simply select the individual result sets it runs in <1s however when I do the simple join, I had to kill the execution because it was at 10 minutes and taking up 99.9% of the eDTU's in the pool.  Please take my word for it that this is a simple join on a tiny result set.

I replaced the CTE's with table variables and got the same result.  I then replaced the table variables with temp tables (#tables) and voila! The query ran in ~2s...

Is somebody aware of a cap or throttling?  Here is a graph of the database usage stats for the past 8 days or so:

[image]

As you can see, early on 6/27 things just started going haywire...Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, the other databases in the pool are averaging ~3% COMBINED of our eDTU's